# "macro not found: _after_build" Ant error building hybris with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, ant, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm trying to get the internal ant tool working with the hybris ecommerce suite.
When I'm invoking ant from the console, it works fine.

Using the Ant tool supplied by IntelliJ, I get the following error message when invoking the "all" target:

```
F:\pathtohybrisinstall\bin\platform\resources\ant\util.xml:130: macro not found: _after_build
at de.hybris.ant.taskdefs.CallMacro.execute(CallMacro.java:58)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor80.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.TryCatchTask.execute(TryCatchTask.java:207)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:396)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.start(Main.java:198)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.main(Main.java:286)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.intellij.rt.ant.execution.AntMain2.main(AntMain2.java:30)
```

Comment: makes me wonder why it was happy with _before_build

Comment: well it's not the first error message - it fails already at _before_all. So i guess it's something with those macros

Comment: I met the same issue as I run ant extgen from the IntelliJ IDE directly. I can bypass this through running the ant command through terminal. It gives me build successful message. Meanwhile, the error message (macro not found) when running directly from IntelliJ actually does not affect anything. You can still move forward ok, or at least by now, I didn't see any negative effect due to this error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your subsequent comment I imagine that the extname param is not being set correctly.

Are you simply calling ant build from your IDE? I would take a look at codegen.xml which is used for the Eclipse integration. There are a few settings imported prior to calling gensource. One of these is importing the contrib library that contains the trycatch target that prevents errors like the one you see there. Perhaps that is related but I am not sure.

Basically, we support Eclipse by default.

Comment: Im trying to run the ant build from my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) - correct.
You might have a point there: I have the option to add additional classpaths when running the build, and after adding hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\lib, I'm able to get a different error message: "...antmacros.xml:173: taskdef A class needed by class de.hybris.fileanalyzer.FileAnalyzerAntTask cannot be found: org/apache/log4j/Logger"

Comment: yes so i should imagine this is all down to classpath setup in ant

Comment: I'm awarding the bounty to this answer, because I think it bumped me into the right direction. Not sure if I will be able to fix it with the given info though.

Comment: I've diffed the outputs of ant -diagnostics (created a diagnostics target), and modified the classpath in a way so it looks the same as the console version. Still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Due to description from [IntelliJ IDEA Help center](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/ant.html), Ant integration is shipped with IntelliJ IDEA, that means, that the Ant you run via console is not the same, that the one used by IDE.

So the exception could be caused by  versions incompatibility. You can change the Ant distibution, used by IDE, in your build file properties on execution tab. Just provide there aa Ant distribution you use in your console.

Comment: That was my first thought as well, so I specified the ant distribution that came with hybris (which is the same that I use on the console). But still no luck.

Comment: Really curiously, if it was the same ant instance. May be some environment. Try to create a custom task, to print out the ant version and classpath to compare the otput from console and IDE

Comment: which ant version and intellij are you using?

Comment: @Stanislav: I've just diffed the output of both, and both seem to use the same java and ant version.

Comment: @WinstonSmith: IJ 14.1.5 Ultimate and the hybris supplied Ant version 1.9.1 (but doesn't matter if I change it to 1.9.4. which is bundled with IntelliJ)

Answer (score 0):

intellij IDEA did not  support ant-contrib try/catch block which is used in hybris build. There are multiple fixes to ant in intellij 2017.2. 
When you import your hybris project using [Hybris Integration](https://bitbucket.org/AlexanderBartash/impex-editor-intellij-idea-plugin/overview) plugin it'll set up all ant related settings for you.

You can install it to your IDE directly from the [repository](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7525) by clicking on the "Browse Repositories" button in Settings/Plugins dialog.